# Populate Two Drop Down Lists in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

- I have 3 tables.
- `company` table, `departments` table and `imei numbers` table.
- There are 2 drop down lists.
- First one companies list from database.
- Once you select a company, it should show all the IMEI numbers of the selected company and the second drop down list with the department list from database for the selected company.

Code:

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT `imei` FROM `devicemanager` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' ORDER BY `imei` ASC");
```

- Now a company is selected.
- then you select a department from the next list.
- Then it should show all the IMEI numbers of the selected department and the selected company.

Code:

```
 $query = mysql_query ("SELECT `imei` FROM `devicemanager` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' AND `depid` = '".$_SESSION['depid']."' ORDER BY `imei` ASC");
```

- If you want to select another department of the same company, it should show all the IMEI numbers of the second department and the selected company.
- Up to this point everything work fine.
- I have used an `IF` loop for this.
- It checks the session variable value of depid `$_SESSION['depid']`.
- When you want to view imei numbers of another company, you select another company.
- Then the `$_SESSION['companyid']` will be changed.
- But the `$_SESSION['depid']` will remain with the depid of the previously selected department.
- So, as the `$_SESSION['depid']` is not empty, `else` part will be executed again.
- It means

Code:

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT `imei` FROM `devicemanager` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' AND `depid` = '".$_SESSION['depid']."' ORDER BY `imei` ASC");
```

will be executed.

- But, in this query `$_SESSION['companyid']` will be the company id of the secondly selected company and the `$_SESSION['depid']` will be the department id of a previously selected department.
- It means the `$_SESSION['depid']` doesn't belong to the selected `$_SESSION['companyid']`.
- There is no any IMEI number for that combination in the database.
- So, it doesn't give the IMEI number list of the secondly selected company as the query can't be executed.
- I tried with `unset($_SESSION['depid'])` also, but it didn't work.
- **HOW TO VIEW IMEI NUMBERS LIST OF THE SECONDLY SELECTED COMPANY, WHEN ALREADY HAVE SELECTED A COMPANY WITH A DEPARTMENT ?**
- Is there another way to do this? more than `IF` loop

*Whole Code Work*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //$_SESSION['companyid'] = $_POST['companyid'];
    //$_SESSION['depid'] = $_POST['depid'];
(isset($_POST['companyid']) ? $_SESSION['companyid'] = $_POST['companyid'] : unset($_SESSION['companyid']));
(isset($_POST['depid']) ? $_SESSION['depid'] = $_POST['depid'] : unset($_SESSION['depid']));

    include "dbconnect.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='comp' value='".$_SESSION['companyid']."'/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='dept' value='".$_SESSION['depid']."'/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='dept2' value='".$_SESSION['depid2']."'/>";

        echo "<form method='post'>";
        if ($_SESSION['depid'] == 0){
            $companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
            echo "<select name='companyid' id='companyid' onchange='form.submit()'>";
            echo "<option value=''>Select Company</option>";
            $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `company` ORDER BY `companyid` ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<option ".(($_SESSION['companyid'] == $row['companyid'])? 'selected==selected':'')." value='".$row['companyid']."'>".$row['company']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></br>";

            $depid = $_POST['depid'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT `depid`, `department` FROM `department` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' ORDER BY `depid` ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            echo  "</br>";
            echo "<select name='depid' id='depid' onchange='form.submit()'>";
            echo "<option value=''>Select Department</option>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<option ".(($_SESSION['depid'] == $row['depid']) ? 'selected==selected':'')." value='".$row['depid']."'>".$row['department']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></br>";
            //$query = "SELECT `depid`, `department` FROM `department` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."'";
            //echo $query;
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT `depid`, `department` FROM `department` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."'") or die (mysql_error());

            echo "<table>";
            echo     "<tr>";
            echo         "<th>IMEI NO.</th>";       
            echo     "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            $query = mysql_query ("SELECT `imei` FROM `devicemanager` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' ORDER BY `imei` ASC");
            echo "<table>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo     "<td>".$row['imei']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        else {
            $companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
            echo "<label>test</label>";
            echo "<select name='companyid' id='companyid' onchange='form.submit()'>";
            echo "<option value=''>".$row['company']."</option>";
            $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `company` ORDER BY `companyid` ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<option ".(($_SESSION['companyid'] == $row['companyid'])? 'selected==selected':'')." value='".$row['companyid']."'>".$row['company']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></br>";

            $depid = $_POST['depid'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT `depid`, `department` FROM `department` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' ORDER BY `depid` ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            echo "</br>";
            echo "<label>test</label>";
            echo "<select name='depid' id='depid' onchange='form.submit()'>";

            echo "<option value=''>Select Department</option>"; 

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<option ".(($_SESSION['depid'] == $row['depid']) ? 'selected==selected':'')." value='".$row['depid']."'>".$row['department']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></br>";

            //$query = "SELECT `imei` FROM `devicemanager` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' AND `depid` = '".$_SESSION['depid']."'";
            //echo $query;
            echo "<table>";
            echo     "<tr>";
            echo         "<th>IMEI NO.</th>";       
            echo     "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";

            $query = mysql_query ("SELECT `imei` FROM `devicemanager` WHERE `companyid` = '".$_SESSION['companyid']."' AND `depid` = '".$_SESSION['depid']."' ORDER BY `imei` ASC");
            echo "<table>"; 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            echo     "<tr>";
            echo         "<td>".$row['imei']."</td>";
            echo     "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        echo "</form>";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appears there may be some extraneous `\`` characters (e.g. `else {\`` ) in your code block that are probably left over from attempting to format the code. Please check over your code in the question to verify that these characters are actually in the code you are using. Please remove them if they are not in your actual code.

Comment: Your code is prone to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you really should sanitize your queries and use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Change the code:

```
$_SESSION['companyid'] = $_POST['companyid'];
$_SESSION['depid'] = $_POST['depid'];
```

to:

```
(isset($_POST['companyid']) ? $_SESSION['companyid'] = $_POST['companyid'] : unset($_SESSION['companyid']));
(isset($_POST['depid']) ? $_SESSION['depid'] = $_POST['depid'] : unset($_SESSION['depid']));
```

Comment: Can't we do this with mysql ? Coz, otherwise I'll have to study mysqli from the beginning.

Comment: Mysql is old. You really should use mysqli.

Comment: it gives an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test_b.php on line 5"